# Add spinner to ActionBar instead on action item

Tags: android, layout, android-spinner

I have an application with sliding menu (Navigation Drawer), ActionBar Title and Menu.

[image]

So there are 3 elements in ActionBar already. How do I add spinner to it with some items (filters)?

[image]

I don't know how to put exactly in that position where action items usually are.

Comment: Use a custom action bar

Comment: If you need just something like spinner, you may use sub-items for menu and make them checkable - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: any code examples how to do that?